# How to set release/debug mode to compile a cpp file at a command prompt using Microsoft C++ toolset

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, cl

I have [a code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967403/custom-memory-manager-works-fine-in-release-mode-but-not-in-debug-mode) that works fine in VS2019 release x86 mode but not in debug mode. Is there any way to use the release mode feature in the command line? For example an option for CL or link.exe. The CL command line syntax is

> CL [option...] file... [option | file]... [lib...] [@command-file] [/link link-opt...]

Here is the list of MSVC compiler options:
[MSVC Compiler Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2019)
There are some optimization options such as `/O1` `/O2` but they don't produce the same results as the VS release build. Am I searching for the wrong thing? Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update**

I found out the correct option for my code is `/MD` for Runtime Library setting. So using the following line in command prompt, the release-mode results are reproduced:

```
>cl /MD app.cpp
```

Comment: If your code doesn't work in debug mode it's probably undefined behaviour somewhere and a really bad idea to circumvent the problem by just compiling it in another way. The release mode won't fix the bug, but just make it worse by taking away runtime checks.

Comment: I agree with you. I know my code needs some improvements and has memory access problems but I think CL is automatically optimizing it and I just wanted to see if I can reproduce the release-mode results in command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's configuration properties for your project will tell you exactly what compiler and linker options are being used in each build configuration.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice the wide range of options in the VS configuration properties. I found out the correct option for my code is `/MD` (Multithreaded DLL) for the Runtime Library setting.